# Show that a continuous function takes all values between its minimum and maximum

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given the epsilon-delta definition of a continuous function:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0: |x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$$

And given the function's maximum value $M$ and minimum value $m$, how can I prove that this function will output all values in the range $(M, m)$?

Comment: Let the function $f$ attain the minimum $m$ at $x=a$ and the maximum $M$ at $x=b$. Then, the conclusion immediately follows from the [intermediate value theorem (IVT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) for continuous functions. In fact, we also have that $f([a,b])=[m,M]$.

Comment: For reference, a much, much more general result is that [the continuous image of a connected space is connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected). If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m, M\in \overline{f(\mathbb{R})}$, then we must have $[m, M]\subseteq \overline{f(\mathbb{R})}$, so $(m, M)\subseteq f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I would be surprised if this Q is not a duplicate.